# How to debug custom theme layout in magento 2

Tags: layout, magento2, xml

Today when i check var/system.log

> [2015-10-26 19:43:28] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the
> 'page.bottom' element cannot be added as child to
> 'page.bottom.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>
> [2015-10-26 19:43:28] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout:
> LAYOUT_frontend_STORE3_4d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e: Please
> correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

Anyone have any clues about fix this problems. Homepage and category page is fine but product detail get empty blank
I have check all layout in my theme but not found any error. All layout files copy from app/code/Magento

I'm using magento master 1.0 beta

You can see my theme from [github](https://github.com/mrtuvn/ves.market.v2)

Answer (score 1):

The messages you specified are not related to your problem.
The **first step** to debug "not showing" state is to see JavaScript errors in a browser developer console.
The **second step** is to see network request and responses in a browser developer console.
If there are no errors found at the 1 and 2 steps then please make sure that you have set PHP `error_reporting` on the maximum level (not dismiss `E_NOTICE` and `E_WARNING`) and enable `display_errors`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I got some error with image object of product in master branch.(Call function with non-object) I already  add product image in backend  
How to fix or update code to master branch

Comment: It is not related to your initial question.